# wxpython infinite refresh panel cause program collapse

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython, refresh, panel

I met a problem when I try to use Wxpython + OpenCV to implement face detection.

Basically, my idea is design a GUI contains detected frames and two buttons. One is for start and the other is for stop. I use a panel as a container to display each frame, and infinitely refresh the panel within a very little time interval.

But when I run the program, If I click the start button, the program will collapse 2 second latter. And the stop button seems useless even before the program collapse.

I think it is the thread problem. Since the whole UI is a big loop, and If I need to refresh one of the component, say panel, all the time, I need to use different thread apart from the main thread.

Is that right? If yes, how should I do? If no, Please give me some extra hints.

thanks a million~! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't refresh unless you have to. Refreshing needlessly is not the way to go. Only refresh when something changes. If you're using a thread to update a wxPython GUI component, then you need to be sure to use wxPython threadsafe methods, like wx.CallAfter, wx.CallLater or wx.PostEvent. See any of the following for more information on threads and wxPython:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/Non-Blocking%20Gui
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

Comment: Thank you very much. Your reply is very useful to me, especially the first one : http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

Comment: wxPython also has convenience module for running multithreaded tasks: `wx.lib.delayedresult`. I have no idea why it is omitted all the time.

Comment: Because I always forget about it ;)